# Flutter - CircularProgressIndicator always running

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I do a search in database (firebase firestore) and I would like the screen to behave as follows: While the search is running, show a CircularProgressIndicator. When the search is finished, if data has been found, show the data. Otherwise, show the "records not found" message. My problem is that the CircularProgressIndicator display is in an eternal loop. What do I do?

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStreamOfBooks() {
    return bookCollection.snapshots();
  }
```

j

```
 body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: repository.getStreamOfBooks(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
              } else {
                return Text("Records not found");
              }
            } 
            else {
              return Dialog(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                  child: new Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        new Text("Loading")
                      ]));
            }
          })
```

## Edit 1 - Trying Future Builder

```
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getStreamOfBooks() async {
    bookCollection.snapshots();
  }

 body: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: repository.getStreamOfBooks(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
              }
              else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return Text("No data");
              }
              return Dialog(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                  child: new Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        new Text("Loading")
                      ]));
            }),
```

Error message: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#41a05):
The getter 'documents' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: documents

Comment: At the moment I don't have data. I was expecting the message "Records not found" to be showed but as I said is not showing because CircularProgressIndicator is looping

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following:

```
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getBooks() async {
    bookCollection.getDocuments();
  }

 body: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          future: repository.getBooks(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
              } 
              else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return Text("No data");
              }
               return Dialog(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                  child: new Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        new Text("Loading")
                      ]));
          })
```

`ConnectionState.done` means it returned data, `ConnectionState.waiting` means its still waiting for the asynchronous operation to finish, and `ConnectionState.none` means it returned no data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code but gave me an error: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> a build function returned null

Comment: Ok, the error is gone but I'm back to CircularProgressIndicator looping. Is possible that the problem is related with my getStreamOfBooks() method? I don't know, like something missing

Comment: use `futurebuilder` instead of `streambuilder`

Comment: Changed to FutureBuilder, now I'm getting "The getter 'documents' was called on null" error

Comment: Where do u get that?

Comment: I edited my answer with #edit 1 to show the full code after changing to FutureBuilder. The error appears when the screen is initialized

Comment: thanks for your updated answer but I got the same error "The getter 'documents' was called on null"

Comment: Write print(snapshot.data) inside connectionstate.done and tell me what you get? are you sure you have data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215048/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-carpi-del-piero).